# About use jinterop get windows event log

Tags: java

when i run the code below:

```
JISession dcomSession = JISession.createSession(domain, user, pass);
dcomSession.useSessionSecurity(false);
JIProgId id =  JIProgId.valueOf("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
id.setAutoRegistration(true);
JIComServer wbemLocatorComObj = new JIComServer(id, host,dcomSession);
```

exception occurs:

```
    org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException: Access is denied, please check whether the [domain-username-password] are correct. Also, if not already done please check the GETTING STARTED and FAQ sections in readme.htm. They provide information on how to correctly configure the Windows machine for DCOM access, so as to avoid such exceptions.  [0x00000005]
    at org.jinterop.winreg.smb.JIWinRegStub.winreg_CreateKey(JIWinRegStub.java:310)
    at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer.initialise(JIComServer.java:510)
    at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer.<init>(JIComServer.java:414)
    at main.java.EventLogListener.getWmiLocator(EventLogListener.java:43)
    at main.java.EventLogListener.main(EventLogListener.java:87)
Caused by: org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIRuntimeException: Access is denied, please check whether the [domain-username-password] are correct. Also, if not already done please check the GETTING STARTED and FAQ sections in readme.htm. They provide information on how to correctly configure the Windows machine for DCOM access, so as to avoid such exceptions.  [0x00000005]
    at org.jinterop.winreg.IJIWinReg$createKey.read(IJIWinReg.java:459)
    at ndr.NdrObject.decode(NdrObject.java:36)
    at rpc.ConnectionOrientedEndpoint.call(ConnectionOrientedEndpoint.java:137)
    at rpc.Stub.call(Stub.java:113)
    at org.jinterop.winreg.smb.JIWinRegStub.winreg_CreateKey(JIWinRegStub.java:304)
    ... 4 more
```

I 'm sure the host domian user password is ok, when `JIProgId id =  JIProgId.valueOf("InternetExplorer.Application");` it works, but why above doesn't work?

Please give me some advice!

Comment: Are you using Administrator level credentials?

Comment: Being administrator is not required in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this code:

```
import static org.jinterop.dcom.impls.JIObjectFactory.narrowObject;
import static org.jinterop.dcom.impls.automation.IJIDispatch.IID;

JISession dcomSession = JISession.createSession(domain, user, pass);
JIComServer comServer = new JIComServer(valueOf("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator"), hostname, dcomSession);
IJIDispatch wbemLocator = (IJIDispatch) narrowObject(comServer.createInstance().queryInterface(IID));

Object[] params = new Object[] {
        new JIString(hostname),
        new JIString("ROOT\\CIMV2"),
        JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM(),
        JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM(),
        JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM(),
        JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM(),
        new Integer(0),
        JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM()
};
JIVariant results[] = wbemLocator.callMethodA("ConnectServer", params);
IJIDispatch wbemServices = (IJIDispatch) narrowObject(results[0].getObjectAsComObject());
```

I found it here: http://www.vijaykandy.com/2009/09/windows-management-instrumentation-wmi-from-java/

I think that `dcomSession.useSessionSecurity(false);` causes your trouble.

So, try the tutorial I referenced. I hope all will work.

Comment: appreciate for your help， if connect local machine， can i set hostname and domain with my ip ， is this ok？

Comment: i think there is something wrong with my domian or hostname ， i maybe set wrong。